# prevent OnBeforeUnload() event from happening in refresh/F5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload

I'm using `onbeforeunload` event to perform operations during the closing page.
I do not want the event to happen in the case of `Refresh` / <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Is there a way or other event to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `onbeforeunload` event listens the page state in the browser. Going to another page as well as refreshing will change the page state, meaning `onbeforeunload` will be triggered anyway.

So I think it is not possible to catch only refresh.

But, if you'll listen and prevent `Keypress` via JavaScript, then it can be achieved.

Refresh can be done via <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys, so your goal will be to prevent these actions.

using jQuery [.keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) you can detect these keycodes:

**For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>**

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

---

**For** <kbd>F5</kbd>

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont want to catch the page refresh. I want the page-refresh does not trigger an event.

Comment: What about clicking the refresh icon?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't prevent browser Refresh button via Javascript.

Comment: You can not catch this event?

Comment: As I know it's not possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the keydown listener to check for F5 and set a flag var.

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Detecting refresh with browser button is not that easy/possible.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a message alert onbeforeunload, so my solution was this one:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;
        $("a").click(function(){ window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt; });
        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            if ((e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey) || (e.keyCode == 116)) {
                window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
            }
        });
  });

  function PopIt() { return "My message before leaving"; }
  function UnPopIt()  { /* nothing to return */ }
```

Third line (*$("a").click...*) is to avoid showing the alert when navigating between sections of the web.