# Run the server side method to close the browse

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod

The user must close the browser or tab page, update the Online status that is in the database (to control user access).

For this use the following

JavaScript method:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    PageMethods.LogOut ();
}
```

And the following WebMethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void LogOut ()
{
      // Update the user status
}
```

The problem is that this method is called at all times, when page change, when I update by bitton (F5), 
So how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: @stephen.vakil, this link don't resolve my problem. but thanks

Comment: There is no way to resolve your problem in javascript, as indicated in the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent onbeforeunload event from happening in refresh/F5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536220/prevent-onbeforeunload-event-from-happening-in-refresh-f5)